# Determine the expected number of neutrons in a randomly chosen atom.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The element titanium has five stable occurring isotopes, differing from each other in the number of neutrons an atom contains.  If $X$ is the number of neutrons in a randomly chosen titanium atom, the probability mass function of $X$ is given as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline x & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 \\
\operatorname{Pr}(X=x) & 0.0825 & k & 0.7372 & 0.0541 & 0.0518 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

a) find $k$

b) Determine the expected number of neutrons in a randomly chosen atom.

In order to get the answer of (a), I said that $k = 1 - (P(24) + P(25) + P(26) + P(27) + P(28)) = 0.0744.$

But, to get the answer of (b), I kinda ran out of ideas. I know that $n = 5$, but, I don't know which probability distribution this question follows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first part is correct.

For the second part you'll want:

$$E(x) = \frac{1}{5}\sum_{x=24}^{28}{xP(x)}.$$

Basically average them but weigh each number of neutrons according to its probability.

As for which probability distribution this follows:  It follows a discrete probability distribution, and you're given all of the probabilities of interest explicitly in the table in your image.